# Уместно ли использовать тип unsigned char для хранения чисел

Tags: c, char

Например, если мне нужна целочисленная переменная в диапазоне `[0; 255]` могу я использовать тип `unsigned char`? Появились сомнения по этому поводу, т.к. этот тип обычно используется для хранения символов, а использование в качестве числа будет не совсем очевидно. Интересует, не повредит ли это читабельности программы.

Comment: Можете, можете, мы не против. Но если бы Вы озвучили цель этого мероприятия (ведь на "Хочу странного" сразу же возникает вопрос "А нахрена?") и профиты, которые ожидаете получить, то появился бы предмет для обсуждения...

Comment: строго говоря, для диапазона [0; 255] нужен по крайней мере `unsigned char`

Comment: @Akina, `нужна целочисленная переменная в диапазоне [0; 255]`

Comment: @mega, компилятор сам выбирает каким именно типом будет `char` - `signed` или `unsigned`, в моем случае - последним.

Comment: Вы вот задали вопрос: "Интересует, не повредит ли это читабельности программы". И тут же оправдываете свою ошибку поведением компилятора. Нелогично. В таком контексте ответ может быть только - да, повредит и даже очень!

Comment: @Eanmos Что переменная объявляется потому, что она нужна - это и так понятно. *этот тип обычно используется для хранения символов* да? а стандарт емнип считает, что это целочисленный тип, а ни разу не строковый...

Comment: @mega, не понимаю, почему Вы считаете это ошибкой, вопрос не в технических деталях - *какой там тип будет у `char`*, вопрос в том, можно ли использовать тип, под которым **обычно** понимают **символ**, в качестве целого числа

Comment: @Akina, дело не в том, что считает стандарт, а в том, что считает человек. Например я всегда, когда вижу `char` думаю, что это символьная переменная.

Comment: @Akina, тем более в си нет строкового типа...

Comment: @Eanmos ну переопределите его как какой-нить свой тип вроде `ushortint`, делов-то...

Comment: Ну вот сделайте то, что [предлагает тут ответчик](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default), действительно, загляните limits.h. Может тогда поймете, насколько разные эти 3 типа: `char`, `signed char` и `unsigned char`. А теперь сделайте выводы, какую предварительную инструкцию должен получить человек, читающий ваш код, чтобы понять его правильно.

Comment: @Akina, в таком случае можно было бы использовать `int8_t` :) Вопрос именно про `char`

Comment: @mega, и насколько же они разные? Один знаковый, другой беззнаковый, третий -  или тот или тот.

Comment: @Eanmos, **u**int8_t только.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unsigned char` не хранит символы. Это - числовой тип данных, также как и `signed char`.

Символы представляются типом данных `char`, который может быть как знаковым, так и беззнаковым - и это третий тип данных, который отличается от первых двух.

Поэтому использовать `unsigned char` для хранения чисел - вполне уместно.

Но если вам нужен именно диапазон `[0; 255]` - то правильнее использовать `uint8_t`, а не `unsigned char` - потому что размер `unsigned char` может отличаться от привычного на экзотических платформах, а `uint8_t` либо 8 бит, либо не существует.

Comment: а, если не существует `uint8_t` в то время как существует `unsigned char`, не логичнее использовать `unsigned char`, чтобы программа по крайней мере работала, с учетом замечания @KoVadim'а?

Comment: @mega все зависит от того, насколько критична восьмибитовость числа для работоспособности программы

Comment: Диапазон [0; 255] может обслужить любой целочисленный беззнаковый тип, размером не менее 8 бит. Непосредственно `uint8_t` ему не нужен. Т.е. правильнее использовать все таки `unsigned char`, а не `uint8_t`, как Вы тут советуете.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ для [вопроса с редакцией #1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/674159/1):

Строго говоря, для диапазона [0; 255] нужен по крайней мере `unsigned char`.

> компилятор сам выбирает каким именно типом будет char - signed или unsigned, в моем случае - последним.

Вы вот задали вопрос: "Интересует, не повредит ли это читабельности программы". И тут же оправдываете свою ошибку поведением компилятора. Нелогично. В таком контексте ответ может быть только - да, повредит и даже очень!

Если Вы заботитесь о читабельности кода, то должны по крайней мере убрать из него лишние зависимости.

И да, `char`, `signed char` и `unsigned char` - разные типы данных.

Comment: О каких зависимостях идет речь?

Comment: О зависимостях: компилятора, настроения, погоды и любых других состояниях, которые влияли на вас и ваш код в момент его написания.

Comment: :) Да дело не в `char`, не в `signed char`, и даже не в `unsigned char`, тело в том, что под этими типами, обычно, подразумевается символ **char**acter.

Comment: В таком случае, вопрос оформлен неправильно, с ошибкой. Это двусмысленный тип, и большинство его интерпретируют все таки как signed. И это опять же вредит читабельности.

Answer (score 0):

Строго говоря, ответ "нет". Тому есть несколько причин.

1) неоднократно упомянутая, для хранения целых чисел в диапазоне [0, 255] **почти всегда** можно использовать тип `unsigned char`. То, что на Вашем компиляторе тип `char` беззнаковый, приведет лишь к тому, что попытавшись использовать свой код на другой платформе (другом компиляторе) Вы столкнетесь с непредсказуемым поведением кода.

2) Более важная причина. Стандарт никак не гарантирует, что тип `char` занимает в памяти 8 бит. Да, я не знаю современных платформ, где это было бы не так, но тем не менее, Вы получите код, не соответствующий стандарту. В конце концов, кодировка ASCII неспроста изначально 7-битная. Корректно было бы использовать тип `uint8_t` определенный в заголовочном файле `<stdint.h>`. Но и это надо делать с осторожностью, ибо (provided only if the implementation directly supports the type) (см http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю пункт 1.7 стандарта, то там говорится, что тип char (и unsigned char) занимает как минимум 8 бит.

Comment: "не повредит ли это читабельности программы" -- Вы уверены, что правильно сформулировали ответ? "нет" - не повредит?

Comment: @mega "нет" - ответ на вопрос "уместно ли..."

Comment: @KoVadim все же, в п. 1.7  написано про минимум 8 бит - это *byte*. *characters (char) shall be large enough to store any member of the implementation’s basic character set.* (п.3.9.1), а для этого хватит и 7 бит. Еще раз, я сомневаюсь в существовании платформы, где `char` меньше 8 бит.

Comment: "нет - ответ на вопрос уместно ли..." -- лучше переформулируйте, т.к. это неочевидно